# 3.0 android os to 2.2 android os issues

Tags: android

I've built my project targeting android 3.0, now I have switched to 2.2 to see how it runs. No surprise, I get errors. Just wondering if someone could point me in teh right direction, on my imageViews, setX and setAlpha error. Any ideas?

Also, what is the lowest system you would deploy for 2.2?

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your second question is api level 8.

setAlpha is since api level 1 so you should not have any issue there.

setX is since api level 11, so that wont going to work.

You can also check this compatibility jar:

http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html